# How do you deal with very large dataset when creating the matrix for recommender system?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, sparse-matrix, recommendation-engine

I am trying to create a transaction and product groups matrix but I have a very large transaction data (over 10,000,000 rows) and around 100 product groups. When I try to create a pivot table using this code

```
df.pivot(index='transaction_id', columns='product_group', values='ratings')
```

It returned **values error "Unstacked DataFrame is too big, causing int32 overflow"**

Is there anyway to deal with this issue other than decrease the size of the data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Convert your axes columns to categories:

```
df['transaction_id'] = df['transaction_id'].astype('category')
df['product_group'] = df['product_group'].astype('category')
```

Make a sparse matrix using the encodings:

```
arr = csr_matrix((df['ratings'].values, (df['transaction_id'].cat.codes, df['product_group'].cat.codes)))
```

Then you just have to keep track of the order of your axes (`df['transaction_id'].cat.categories` will give you the labels that should be applied to the rows for example).

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your answer. Is it possible to show the whole table after doing the csr_matrix? I tried to use the code `pd.DataFrame(arr.toarray())` but it returned  MemoryError. (Or is there the way to use the csr_matrix with 'mlxtend' library?)

Comment: If you have enough memory you can make this a dense array. I don't know what that library is. Scikit should take sparse arrays for many ML methods.